# Strcmp does not do the comparing

Tags: c, string, strcmp

Why isn't the comparing between the strings work?
I know for a certain that the `user` strings do not have any endlines at the end of them, but still I get that the username is not accepted.

```
char user[24];
int userLog = -1;

FILE  *usernames;
usernames = fopen("usernames.cfg", "r");

if (usernames == NULL){
    perror("usernames - err");
    return(-1);
}

while(fgets(user, sizeof(user), usernames) !=NULL){

    strtok(user, "\n");
    printf("%s -- %s\n", user, possibleUsername);

    // First edition of question contained:
    // if((possibleUsername, user) == 0)
    // Still having problems with this version:
    if(strcmp(possibleUsername, user) == 0)
        userLog = 1;
    else 
        userLog = 0;

}

if(userLog == 1) printf("Username accepted:   %s\n", possibleUsername);
else if(userLog == 0) printf("Username doesn't exist in the database.\n");
fclose(usernames);
```

usernames.cfg:

```
user
justplayit
etc
```

Comment: `if((possibleUsername, user)` lacks a `strcmp`.

Comment: Could you show the content of `usernames.cfg`? If they're on a new line always they end with newlines but the `user` string doesn't as you said. That might be the problem.

Comment: Still not running properly

Comment: I've put the strcmp function where it belongs. It somehow it must be some type or format difference.

Comment: use need `break;` e.g `userLog = 1;` --> `{ userLog = 1; break;}`

Comment: @cad: that gets handled by the `strtok`. BLUEPIXY nails it - the loop continues over *all* names even though one matched.

Comment: Yeah, I got it, the userLog variable got overwritten.

Comment: What value is in `possibleUsername`?  Use `printf("<<%s>> -- <<%s>>\n", user, possibleUsername);` to show where the boundaries are.  If, for example, `possibleUsername` contains a newline, then the last `>>` will be on its own line (and the original output would have blank lines between entries).  What value did you enter as the name to be matched?

Comment: Your reporting should also cover `userLog == -1` which would happen if there are no names in the database yet.  You'd use an `else` clause to cover any other value in `userLog`, though the only plausible value is -1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose it should be

```
if(strcmp(possibleUsername, user) == 0)
```

Because the expression

```
(possibleUsername, user) == 0
```

is equal to

```
user == NULL
```

## EDIT

Change

```
int userLog = -1;
```

to

```
int userLog = 0;
```

and delete

```
else
    userLog = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{   
    char user[24];
    int userLog;
    FILE* usernames;
    char* userPtr;

    usernames = fopen("usernames.cfg", "r");
    if (usernames == NULL)
    {
        perror("Usernames config not found or read protected");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while(fgets(user, sizeof(user), usernames) != NULL)
    {
        userPtr = strtok(user, "\n");
        if (userPtr != NULL) 
        {
            printf("Username in file => %s", userPtr);
            if (strcmp(userPtr, "find me") == 0)
            {
                userLog = 1;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                userLog = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    if (userLog)
    {
        printf("User find me accepted");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("User find me not in database");
    }

    fclose(usernames);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Its the same program you wrote, but I use an extra pointer returned from strtok to check if any token is found. Comparing this token with a "zero-terminated" string, like your possibleUsername should be, works for me. If possibleUsername is a fixed length character array you are adviced to use strncmp and set the length of the string to compare e.g. strncmp(userPtr, possibleUsername, length) == 0. What could also be the problem if the usernames.cfg file is saved with \r\n so strtok would return "username\r" instead of "username". Maybe you could debug your program and check the buffer of user what content it has. Hope it helps.